# I have fetched data in Android by using PHP Web services it fetched but when new data is added it can't fetched?

Tags: android

By using below code I am fetching data. When I run it the first time it will show all data. When I insert new data it will be inserted successfully but on going to report page and clicking on that it shows previous data and not the new or updated data.

```
public class Fragment_Emp_Report extends Fragment {

    List<Get_EmpNameAdapter> get_empNameAdapter1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    String url = "http://ghawadediilip.000webhostapp.com/Services/jsonFetchName.php";
    String JSON_NAME = "emp_name";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
    RequestQueue  requestQueue;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_emp_report,container,false);

        fetchEmpName();

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        get_empNameAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.report_recyclerview);



        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
    }
    public void fetchEmpName()
    {
        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                jsonFetch(response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener listener = new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request request) {
                recyclerViewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(listener);

    }
    public void jsonFetch(JSONArray array)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
        {
            Get_EmpNameAdapter get_empNameAdapter2 = new Get_EmpNameAdapter();
            JSONObject json=null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                get_empNameAdapter2.setEmpname(json.getString(JSON_NAME));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
            get_empNameAdapter1.add(get_empNameAdapter2);
        }
        recyclerViewadapter = new Report_Recyclerview_Adapter(get_empNameAdapter1,getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fetchEmpName(); called only one time when onCreateView is called if you want to refetch the date when back from another fragment then you have to call your method again you can achieve that by calling it in onResume.